# GridView is empty when passing in Array of images

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using picasso to load images into a grid view. The image URLS are retrieved from a database using the following code. This works as the URLS are outputted to the Android Monitor correctly.

```
private void getImages(){
        String BASE_URL = IMAGES_URL + userDetails.getUID();


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,BASE_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{
                            JSONArray listArray = response.getJSONArray("images");
                            images = new String[listArray.length()];
                            for(int i = 0; i <= listArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject row = listArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = row.getString("image_url");

                                images[i] = name;
                                Log.d(TAG, images[i]);


                            }
                            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), images));

                        } catch (JSONException e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());


            }
        });

        VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

The code for my adapter is:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, String[] imageUrls) {
        mContext = c;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(mContext);
        picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);



        Picasso
                .with(mContext)
                .load("http://178.62.121.73" + imageUrls[position])
                .into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

However, nothing is loaded on my activity. If i move the setadapter into my OnViewCreated, below where the code for downloading the image URLS is, i get a nullpointerexception on the images array, even though it has been successfully populated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the size of ImageArray?if it is 0, I suppose the problems  is in 'reponse' variable which is your JSON parse result.

Comment: Yeah, when i output the array using Log, the array is populated with the URLS for each of the images.